# c++ encryption and decryption source code

Tags: c++, encryption, compiler-errors

i recently started learning c++ online and started working on this code but need some help with the errors the compiler is throwing on me.
basically i just want to get a password from the user if it is the first time by using 'flag' variable and write the password in an encrypted form onto a text file . 
if the user isn't logging in for the first time and has a password saved then read the encrypted text, de-crypt it and check wether it is equal to the password entered by the user.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
char encryptpass(char *pass) //function to encrypt 
 {

   for( int i=0; pass[i] != '\0'; ++i )
   char enpass[10]= ++pass[i];
   return(enpass);


}
 char decryptpass(char *str)  // function to decrypt
{
for( ; str!='\0'; ++str )
char depass[10]= --str;
return(depass);

}

 int main()             // main function
{
int flag=0;
if(flag=0)
{
    cout<<"enter your password";
    char pass[10];
    cin>>pass;
    fstream file("userpass.txt",ios::in | ios::out);
    file<<enpass[10];
}
else
{
  cout<<"enter password";
  cin>>pass;
   bool check=false;
   static char str[10];
   file.seekg(ios::beg);
   file >> str;
   file.close();
   decryptpass(str);

     if(pass=depass)   // decrypted password is equal to input password ?
   {
       check=true;      // set boolen value to true
   }
 else
 {
   cout<<"incorrect password";
 }
   return(0);
 }    // end of main
```

the compiler gives these errors-----

```
warning : In function 'void encryptpass(char*)':
line 9 error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
line 9 warning: unused variable 'enpass' [-Wunused-variable]
line 10 error: 'enpass' was not declared in this scope
line 10 error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
warning : In function 'void decryptpass(char*)':
line 17error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
line 17 warning: unused variable 'depass' [-Wunused-variable]
line 18 error: 'depass' was not declared in this scope
line 18 error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
warning : In function 'int main()'
line 25 warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]

line 31 error: 'enpass' was not declared in this scope
line 36 error: 'pass' was not declared in this scope
line 39 error: 'file' was not declared in this scope
line 43 error: 'depass' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: You didn't ask, but I think you should know that that's not at all the right way to do passwords.  Concerning the code itself... Learn how never to get into a mess like this. Start a project by writing just a tiny bit of code.  Get that little bit to compile and do the right thing. (The "right thing" at this point will be not much.) Add a bit more, compile and test. And so on and so on. Once you get the hang of it, "the error" will be easy to find, because it will be the last thing you changed.

Comment: i would surely re-write the code following the suggested method . thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You compiler output doesn't appear to match your source, e.g. the return type of `encryptpass` is `void` according to the compiler.

The first error is because `char empass[10]` is a declaration for a `char` array of size 10, but you are using it like a char lvalue. So first declare it before the for loop:

```
char empass[10];
```

Then in the for loop you would set the i-th element of the encoded password with

```
empass[i] = ++pass[i];
```

However, your code is also modifying the password that you passed to the function: `++pass[i]` increments `pass[i]` by one. Is that really what you want?

Comment: what i thought was , in the encrypt function the password would be incremented and then would be written to the textfile. while decrypting the password would again be decremented to the original text. is the logic wrong?

Comment: the compiler output and code mismatch appears to happen becausei tried solving the errors by changing the return type of the functions .

Comment: Nothing wrong with the logic, but quite a few problems with your code.

Why would you post the compiler output from an older version of your code? Here is what happens when I [compile the code you posted](http://ideone.com/Z0hs61).

Comment: with all the help and input from you guys , i managed to bring down the error count to 1 , but cant fix that one --

Comment: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token on line 11 .